# {react, antd}How do i create a clickable event for the card icon

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm currently working on a react portfolio and wanted to explore ant design, one of the final steps I currently need to do is make the actions clickable events/a href that go over to github. I've looked everywhere and cant figure it out.

This is the current model

```
// input projects into cards
import React from 'react';


import { Card, Avatar, Tag} from 'antd';
import {GithubOutlined,LinkOutlined} from '@ant-design/icons';


const { Meta } = Card;



export function ProjectList() {
  
  return (
      <Card
        style={{ width: 300 }}
        cover={
          <img
            alt="example"
            src="https://gw.alipayobjects.com/zos/rmsportal/JiqGstEfoWAOHiTxclqi.png"
          />
        }
        actions={[
          <GithubOutlined key="github" type="link">
            <Tag>
              <a href="https://ant.design/components/card/">

              </a>
              
            </Tag>
          </GithubOutlined>,
          <LinkOutlined key="link" href=""/>
        ]}
      >
        <Meta
          avatar={<Avatar src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png" />}
          title="Card title"
          description="This is the description"
        />
      </Card>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing add `div` outside of the card with `onClick`:

```
<div onClick={() => alert("Hello from here")}>
    <Card></Card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, since it's going to an external link and icons are already clickable events, you just surround the icon with `<a>` tag and it works.

```
<a href="">
    <LinkOutlined key="link" href=""/>
</a>
```